# Volume boot record virus infection

Tags: malware

My pc have a RAT which survive after system format.
It's fully undetectable from any antivirus software and av rescue disks ...
I've tried to flash my BIOS.
Then i used that command from linux termimal to delete everything + MBR :

> dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=1

And the only thing that remain is  the VBR.
So,let's say that my computer is infected with VBR virus.
What are the mechanism to remove it?

Edit: I used this guide to clean the BIOS:
https://smallbusiness.chron.com/cleanse-virus-bios-79706.html

Well i just don't know where the virus may hide ...So i done nearly everything i found on net :D

Any help will be hightly appreciated !

Comment: Try TDSS Killer (Kaspersky) to delete root kit viruses.

Comment: what steps did you take to clean your BIOS?

Comment: If you fully formatted a drive, there isn’t any way you still have, an infection on the drive.

Comment: @Jasen what does BIOS have to do with this?

Comment: it's just another place that could be infected

Answer (score 0):

That dd command will zero out the first 512 bytes of the disk - so it will erase the volume boot record.  If you are wanting to better erase the disk, you may want to use a block size (bs) of 4096 instead.

If you are wanting to nuke it so nothing remains on the disk, you can overwrite the whole disk with

```
 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1M
```

This will take a while, but will overwrite the entirety of a hard drive.  (There may be residual data on an SSD due to write overprovisioning, but nothing a virus could access)

Of-course, any of the above commands will delete your data (or make it appear to be deleted to the OS)